# laser diode problem

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I'm a student studying chemistry, i'm working with diode laser to look at emission spectra for certain complexes. i'm using integrating sphere as my setup, when i use the 405nm diode laser output of 4.5mw, i'm getting a small emission peak at 600nm in my background and sample, any idea why that could be, whats causing it? i've used other wavelengths with the same power and had no issues.

Comment: Fluorescence? I mean that´s what you´re looking for anyway, isn´t it?

Comment: The OP mentioned it is present both in the sample and in the background. So basically he is looking either for some unwanted 600 nm radiation emitted by the 405 nm laser or fluorescence from a contaminant present in the chamber, that would absorb at 405 nm and emit at 600 nm.

Comment: thank you PLD, thats exactly what i meant. i don't think its a contaminant because it happens every time i use that laser, i've changed the sample and the cuvette is clean but  it still happens so i believe is the laser, i'm just wonder what could cause that?

Comment: If you believe it is due to the illumination by the laser, you could try to get a spectrum of your laser with a calibrated photometer. Or for a quick check, you could in the sample holder something that might disperse more of the excitation light and see if it goes up. Just be careful not to send too much power of the laser to the detector as it might damage it (this is if you use a grating spectrophotometer to measure your spectrum).

Comment: i did it with a CCD. i want to find what is happening to cause the laser peak to have another emission peak at 600nm? this is happening with the blank sample, i've ran over 22 samples and it in each one

Comment: The simplest way is to use a yellow/orange cut-off filter, the 405 nm will be absorbed and the red transmitted, say, onto a piece of white paper.

Comment: porphyrin i'm trying to work out why its there in the first place? are you saying if i use a yellow/orange cut-off filter, that could remove the peak?

Comment: If it comes from your laser, you can a) repair the laser, b) buy a new one, c) use a filter, d) ignore it, or e) subtract it with the background. Could be it´s normal with the laser type you have.

Comment: karl i've been subtracting it from my background but in my report i need to comment on it and say what might be causing it, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I just did the experiment suggested by @porphyin. I used a 405 nm laser diode built into a toy "Space Gun" and the orange long pass filter shown in the figure below:

[image: Space Gun]

The results are in the next dark figure:

[image: Results]

The spots on the paper are *not* fluorescence of the paper (see the violet fluorescence of the paper around the dark shadow of the filter) and are *not* due to fluorescense of the orange long pass filter. So it appears that the 405 nm laser diode has some parasitic longer wavelength emission. It can be filtered out using non-fluorescent short pass filters.

Comment: thank you! do you know why it might have that?

Comment: Actually, no. But unwanted emission is fairly common in LEDs. My 397 nm LEDs have some red emission from the LED and the colorless plastic case emits some green.  So I used **non-fluorescent filters** to get rid of that. The filter in the photos is not non-fluorescent, but it was in one of my junk drawers and was fit for this purpose.

Comment: thank you.  i understand how to remove it from future experiments so thats not an issue for me. i need to write in my report what could be causing that to happen

Comment: Please consider giving the green checkmark to the most helpful of the posted answers. It encourages people to put some thought and time into crafting answers that are factually correct, relevant, understandable and likely to be of benefit to those, in future, who encounter the question and accepted answer. It is a small reward for those who volunteer their considerable time, effort and experience to aid others and they might well look favorably at future questions from the same person. Thanks for considering this!