# Why turmeric turns green?

Tags: acid-base

When I added some turmeric solution to a strong base it should have turned red but to my surprise it did change colour but became green and when I added some more base and stirred it turned red! Why did this happen and it is happens quite often with people according to the data I have!

Comment: Post some images regarding that because I personally never experienced that. In my experience when I put some soap in turmeric powder solution it turns red watch this https://youtu.be/Olezbt9cxfo. By the way you will have ear some reputation first to use images in your questions.

Comment: Tumeric has a beautiful green fluorescence, btw, but that is usually visible in bright sunlight and in UV it is a very bright green.  Were you doing this experiment outdoors?Interesting observation. Is your tumeric adulterated, which is so common thing these days? What base did you add. Can you try a different brand?

Comment: No , I did it in kitchen and it only happened once ,never again.But why?

Comment: Try a different brand. Maybe your container was contaminated with some pigment. When you cannot repeat an experiment chances are there was a mistake. Was you strong base pure? Which base did you use?

Comment: See https://www.compoundchem.com/2016/11/30/turmeric/amp/   The fluorescence visibility may depend on light source, concentration  and angle of observation.

Comment: @Poutnik Nice link! I may try this just for fun, since I have everything necessary! Thanks!

Comment: I just upvoted so you can post pics if you wish. Using my 405 nm [Space gun](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/130935/79678), I zapped my bottle of turmeric and it fluoresced yellow. I dissolved a little in pure ethanol and it fluoresced green when I zapped it at 405 nm. Next I will add a dash of water and a sodium hydroxide flake and see what happens to the fluorescence.

Comment: @EdV It might be possible it works for white LED or (cold white) fluorescent light too.

Comment: Ed: If you have cooking oil, let tumeric soak in it. You will see beautiful greenish yellow fluorescence even under white fluorescent light. Long time ago, I planned to use magnifying glass as a poor man's Xenon arc lamp and it works. Even quinine water begins to glow blue with magnifying glass.

Comment: @EdV, Heat the baking soda to convert it into sodium carbonate. I think the OP saw the fluorescence at an angle.  The natural fluorescence appears only on the surface.

Comment: This is what the fluorescence of turmeric solutions looks like: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/79678. I will post temporary better (unbloomed and in focus) photos if I can get them. The basic solution was obtained by dropping small pieces of partially oxidized calcium metal into the cuvette.

Comment: Okay,I used surf for base and  unbranded turmeric.

Comment: I saw the images it wasn't that bright it was like a normal grass green.

Comment: The photos are for laser-excited fluorescence, which is not what you saw. The odds are you had contamination or an adulterated turmeric. In any event, none of us can guess what caused your irreproducible observation, so that pretty much closes the case. If it ever happens again, you can get photos, document the turmeric specifics, and edit your question.

Comment: @MohdSaad, Surf (detergent brand) has plenty of chemicals. This is not a strong base. EdV's results are authentic. It was nice of him that he did experiments for you.